# Using Subprocess to Check sudo-apt install Return Value?

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess, sudo

I'm currently writing a shell script using Python 2.7. To install virtual-env I am using the following:

```
def setup_virtal_env(package): 
    try: 
        subprocess.call('apt-get update', shell=True)
        command = subprocess.call("apt-get install python-" + package, shell=True)
        proc = subprocess.check_call(str(command), stdin=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        stdoutdata, stderrdata = proc.communicate(),
        assert proc.returncode == 0, 'Installed failed...'
        print proc.returncode
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError: 
        print >> sys.stderr, "Execution failed", 'OSError,', 'trying pip...'
        'Installed virtualenv with pip...' if install_pip(package) else 'Pip failed...'
```

My question is how can I use `subprocess.check_call` or `subprocess.check_output` to check if the user already has `virtualenv` installed or if it installed correctly. As of right now when I call `.check_call()` it returns:

```
File "install_.py", line 121, in setup_virtal_env
proc = subprocess.check_call(str(command), stdin=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is there a way I can use `subprocess` to check if `virtualenv` is installed correctly?

Comment: unrelated: the terminology is misleading `apt-get`  installs system packages. They can but they do not create virtualenvs as a rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use a command with arguments, you need to pass an array of args, like

```
suprocess.check_call(["apt-get","install", ...], ...)
```

Otherwise, the system will try to find an executable literally named "apt-get update", because spaces are legal filename characters. Of course it will then fail, giving you that error.

If you want to use a single string for your command, remember to use the `shell=True` argument

```
suprocess.check_call("apt-get install", shell=True, ...)
```

Comment: Awh, ok so I tried the following and I still get the same error, unfortunately... `proc = subprocess.check_call(["apt-get install python-", str(package)], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: You've missed the point, that command should be `subprocess.check_call(["apt-get", "install", "python-", str(package)], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`. Have you ever done C or Java and had to use the `char *argv` or `String[] args` from main? This is populating that array.

Comment: Awwh, @user2085282 thanks so much, yeah apologizes its been a long day. I appreciate the C explanation makes total sense.

Comment: I appear to have made a mistake, I was looking at the wrong line in your code. If you use `shell=True` then it will break down the string itself, as its using the shell. If you don't, you will need to do as listed above. Remember to be consistent.

Comment: @user2808315: you want `"python-"+package` as a *single* argument, not two.